# как передать переменную из одного хендлера в другой на aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram, handlers

Всем привет. Я пишу бота на aiogram. Там есть оплата через киви, также там генерируется комментарий для оплаты. Сначала предлагается выбрать срок, на который хочет вложится юзер(допустим на неделю, через неделю он получает свой процент). Этот срок нужно перенести в комментарий для оплаты, чтобы я знал когда связаться с юзером.

```
async def callnull(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_money = db.user_money(callback.from_user.id)
    db.set_money(callback.from_user.id, user_money - user_money)
    await callback.message.answer('Вы успешно обнулили свой баланс!\nВеберите срок вложения', reply_markup=n.srok)
```

Далее отправляется сообщение с инлайн кнопками

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'week')
async def srokw(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    time = 'week'
    await callback.message.answer('Теперь введите сумму вложения целым числом')



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'month')
async def srokm(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    time = 'month'
    await callback.message.answer('Теперь введите сумму вложения целым числом')



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data == 'year')
async def sroky(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    time = 'year'
    await callback.message.answer('Теперь введите сумму вложения целым числом')
```

Пользователь выбирает срок вложения, вводит сумму пополнения, далее генерируется комментарий к оплате.
Функция def isNumber проверяет введённую сумму на валидность

```
def isNumber(_str):
    try:
        int(_str)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

@dp.message_handler()
async def oplata(message: types.Message):
    if isNumber(message.text):
        msgMoney = int(message.text)
        if msgMoney >= 50:
            user_comm = '@' + str((message.from_user.username)) + '_' + str(time) + '_' + str(random.randint(100, 999))
            bill = p2p.bill(amount = msgMoney, lifetime = 5, comment = user_comm)
            db.add_check(message.from_user.id, msgMoney, bill.bill_id)
            await message.answer(f'Счет готов к оплате! Переведите на наш QIWI кошелёк {msgMoney} рублей.', reply_markup=n.buy_menu(url=bill.pay_url, bill=bill.bill_id))
        else:
            await message.answer('Минимальная сумма вложения - 50 рублей')
    else:
        await message.answer('Введите целое число!')
```

Пустой хендлер ловит сумму и генерирует счет с комментарием user_comm.
Но при запуске бота python выдает

```
user_comm = '@' + str((message.from_user.username)) + '_' + str(time) + '_' + str(random.randint(100, 999))
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

Вопрос - как мне передать переменную time, чтобы сгенерировался комментарий со сроком, который пользователь выбрал с помощью inline кнопки?
Комментарий в итоге должен выглядеть вот так: @username_week\month\year_123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтоб получить time в другом хандлере его нужно сохранить. В примере https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html смотрите на параметр state

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как использовать этот пример в моем случае

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо Вам большое за помощь, все работает!